# Table update on PK and another field in MySQL is sporadically slow

Tags: mysql, performance, primary-key, innodb

This is interesting case where UPDATE in MySQL is sporadically slow. Background: 48GB Innodb buffer cache, 512MB ib logs. Innodb table with 40mln rows. Structure and indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE `VisitorCompetition` (
  `VisitorCompetitionId` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `CompetitionInstanceId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `Score` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Visits` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `RankAtCompletion` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SessionId` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SharedDate` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedDate` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `LastModifiedDate` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `ModifiedBy` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CaseId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`VisitorCompetitionId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uc_UserId_CompetitionInstanceId` (`UserId`,`CompetitionInstanceId`),
  KEY `idx_VisitorCompetition_TI_S` (`CompetitionInstanceId`,`Status`),
  KEY `IDX_CreatedDate` (`CreatedDate`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`CompetitionInstanceId`) 
    REFERENCES `CompetitionInstance` (`CompetitionInstanceId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=74011154 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

When there is an update which looks like this:

```
update VisitorCompetition 
set    
    Status='CLOSED',
    score=770000,
    visits=null,
    RankAtCompletion=null,
    sharedDate=null,
    LastModifiedDate=current_timestamp(6),
    ModifiedBy='11.12.12.200' 
where VisitorCompetitionId=99999965 and Status = 'CLOSED';
```

Note PK in where clause and additional field as a condition. This update executes ~20 times/sec. On most cases this update runs instantaneously but few times a day it takes 100-300 seconds to complete and it shows up is slow log. What would be a reason for this behavior?

**Update #1:** Ruled out checkpointing, trigger and query cache as a possible root causes. events_stages_history_long shows this for one of the updates:

```
stage/sql/updating      188.025130
stage/sql/end   0.000004
stage/sql/query end     0.000002
stage/sql/closing tables        0.000004
stage/sql/freeing items 0.000002
stage/sql/logging slow query    0.000032
stage/sql/cleaning up   0.000001
```

Similar problem (but not exactly my case): [MySQL update taking(too) long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627794/mysql-update-takingtoo-long-time)

**Update #2:** The slow UPDATES in my case always correlate with spikes in mutex contention. Seems like this is root cause.

Comment: Probably you hit the limit of your innodb log file size, and it had to pause to do a hard flush of dirty pages. The default log file size in older versions of MySQL is ridiculously small for production usage.

Comment: Read https://www.percona.com/blog/2008/11/21/how-to-calculate-a-good-innodb-log-file-size/ and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-data-log-reconfiguration.html

Comment: Great point, Bill! I will check on this and score the win if this is the case.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  Did any other slow query overlap with this one?

Comment: @Rick James: MariaDB 10.0.12. There is one more query (INSERT which also shows up and it takes ~150 seconds to complete). The INSERT however uses random UUID for a column which has unique index on it, so I was blaming index maintenance for its slow performance (which may not be the case)

Comment: Does it involve this table?  SessionId?

Comment: It involves a different table

Comment: @Bill Karwin : is there a way to monitor when checkpoint has occurred? I was monitoring via SHOW INNODB ENGINE STATUS for "Main thread" state and I see it is mostly in sleeping state. Very rare there is "checkpoint" state shows up and it seems to be quickly go away.

Comment: In SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS, look at the section for "LOG". Watch when "Last checkpoint at" changes value.

Comment: There are few other reason why this may happen in addition to checkpoint: 2) Query cache invalidations, 3) Trigger on the table

Comment: If you would like to provide variables and status, I could dig deeper.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis for the data I want.

Answer (score 1):

While there can be many reasons for this, I want to mention what was the root cause in my case. It was an application bug where many hundreds of application sessions were trying to update the same rows, causing lock escalation, mutex contention and as a result slow execution. After our Dev team fixed the code, this issue was instantly resolved. Thanks all.