# How session concurrency is controlled in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, session, concurrency, mariadb

I have mariadb with max_connections = 1000. The application stack opened 450 connections to the database and it is designed to be highly concurrent. The workload is mostly INSERT/UPDATEs. When monitoring via show processlist I am noticing that there are no more then 11 active queries executed in the databases at the same time. I think some of mysql settings prevent more concurrency in my case, but I can't figure out what they are. The mysql set of parameters which control concurrency are totally confusing and it is difficult to see the clarity in there. I have this:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like '%concurr%';
+----------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name              | Value  |
+----------------------------+--------+
| concurrent_insert          | ALWAYS |
| innodb_commit_concurrency  | 0      |
| innodb_concurrency_tickets | 5000   |
| innodb_thread_concurrency  | 32     |
| thread_concurrency         | 10     |
+----------------------------+--------+
```

24 buffer pool instances, 2GB per instance and slow GCP SSD persistent disks.

The last parameter is depreciated (based on my research). What should be changed to increase more concurrency in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re thread_concurrency:

> This variable is deprecated and is removed in MySQL 5.7. You should remove this from MySQL configuration files whenever you see it unless they are for Solaris 8 or earlier.

So, don't bother changing it.

Meanwhile, I would say that your observations are 'normal'.  That is, your 450 connections are doing very fast queries, so that you happen to see only 11 in the middle of something when you look.

Are you seeing any unexpected latency in the app?  I suspect not.

Do you see some particular query more often than the others?  Are any showing up with a `Time` of more than, say, "2"?If either, let's see the query, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Are any `PROCESSLIST` entries saying `Locked`.  If so, look for the query with the largest `Time` that is *not* `Locked` and investigate why it is running so long.

Comment: There is unexpected latency (I have separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45764963/table-update-on-pk-and-another-field-in-mysql-is-sporadically-slow). But I rarely see Time > 0. It is mostly fast. No state shows Locked, only Init or NULL

Comment: Do you often see more than, say, 11 in non-Sleep state?