# How can i optimize update SQL query with "WHERE NOT IN (...more than 1000 items...)"?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I have table with this fields: `ID`, `USERNAME`, `DATA`, and `IS_ONLINE`. Each minute i receive new large part of data from remote server with current online users `[(username, is_online, data), ...]`.

And i need set `IS_ONLINE = 1` only for users in this array and for other users set `IS_ONLINE = 0`. 
In loop i making queries `UPDATE users SET is_online = 1, data = 'data' WHERE username = 'username'`. And then to the set `IS_ONLINE = 0` i execute this query:

`update users set is_online = 0 where username not in ('user1', 'user2', ... , 'user1000')`

And it works well if i have small amount of users, but if users table contains more than 100 thousands lines this query executing more than 50 seconds.

Please can you give me answer or idea how i can increase speed of this simple query.

Thank you!

Comment: . . It takes time to update rows -- locking, logging, and so on.

Comment: 50 seconds? that's not bad performance

Comment: @django-unchained, i think it very bad perfomance to update table with 60.000 lines and 1500 usernames in WHERE NOT IN. Cause if i have only 30000 users in the table this query executing VERY fast.

Comment: Check this thread. You might find some answers there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627794/mysql-update-takingtoo-long-time

Comment: Wow ... can't you put those user-names into a *table?*  Then you could just `JOIN` to that table and you'd be done instantaneously.

Comment: you should really post your current "way" of doing this.. maybe then we can tell you how to do better.

Comment: How long does `update users set is_online = 0` take? Might be faster to start with that, then mark the users who _are_ online, using the process that seems to not take too long.

Comment: @EricBrandt i can't set `is_online = 0` before setting `is_online = 1`, because another appl constantly receives data like `what users is online` and i can't give to this app answer without any info about current online users.

Comment: If you can't do what @EricBrandt suggested because all the individual updates take too long and you don't want to have the `is_online` field to show the "wrong" value for too long, you could add a timestamp column. Then, while executing the individual updates you could set that timestamp of the affected rows to a common value (e.g. the start time of the updates.). Then, at the end, you could just do `update users set is_online = 0 where new_timestamp_column < theStartDate`.

Comment: @MikeRobinson yours idea sounds very good, you mean create table on the disk, db or in memory?

Comment: @Christian great idea! Thank you!

Comment: The trick with the new timestamp column works even better if you create an index for that column. At least worth a try.

Comment: update users set is_online = 0 where is_online = 1 AND username not in ('user1', 'user2', ... , 'user1000') ?

Comment: Put both updates as suggested by @EricBrandt in a transaction. And nobody else will see the intermediate state of the table.

Comment: update a row with the current timestamp for a user's activity and then when you need `is_online=0` grab from a `ts < (currenttime - interval)`. Then you done' need is_online fields. Alternately use redis caches that expire after they aren't accessed for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the `NOT IN` query is touching the entire 100,000 rows.  Let's avoid that by changing the query and the schema.  Instead of setting `is_online` for all users, let's devise a way so that you only have to touch those that are *currently* online.

Instead of having `is_online` being a boolean, let's make it either a `DATETIME` or `BIGINT`.  Then set it to a new, higher, value for those that are online, ignoring the others.

That will need one other bit of info -- the new high value.  Simply store it in another table with a single row with a single column.

This schema avoids the timestamp kludges in the Comments.  The only users that are "online" are those with the latest value in `is_online`; all others are offline.

Now let's check the rest of the schema.  Do you really need both `id` and `username`?  Toss `id` and make `username` the `PRIMARY KEY`; that will speed things up because it won't have to do a double lookup -- first to find the id, given the username, second to get to the row to `UPDATE` it.  (Caveat: There may be issues if it is a `FOREIGN KEY` from another table.  If so, please provide more details.)

Another tip -- Using 1000 statements to touch 1000 rows is a lot slower than using a single query.  To do multiple updates of different values, use IODKU.

I'm hoping this will all boil down to a 3 sql statements:

```
BEGIN;
$hv = SELECT high_value FROM HighValue FOR UPDATE;
$hv++;
INSERT INTO MainTable
    VALUES
        ('user1', 'blah1', $hv),
        ('user2', 'blah2', $hv),
        ...
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        data = VALUES(data),   -- sets the new `data` value
        is_online = $hv ;
UPDATE HighValue SET high_value = $hv;
COMMIT;
```